# pass variables outside a function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a function in AngularJS:

```
function TrendChart(){

      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.datta = [];

      TrendChartFactory.get({kpiItem: $scope.selectedKpiItem.key, puItem: $scope.puName},function(data){
          $scope.trendValues = data;
          console.log($scope.trendValues);
      })

      getKpiValue($scope.selectedKpiItem.key,$scope.trendValues);

}
```

but I want to access $scope.trendValues outside my function like this:

```
function getKpiValue(selectedKPI,trendV) {
     for(var i= 0; i< $scope.trendV.length;i++){
          console.log($scope.trendV[i][selectedKPI]);
          $scope.data.push($scope.trendV[i][selectedKPI]);
     }
     $scope.datta.push($scope.data);
     console.log($scope.datta);
}
```

But it obviously I get an error that it is undefined. How can i fix this ?

Comment: are both function in same controller?

Comment: yes, they are in the same function

Comment: When you are calling the function getKpiValue you are passing $scope.trendValues as a parameter. Within getKpiValue you can refer trendV as simply trendV not as $scope.trendV

Comment: but in function getKpiValue you are using the parameter trendV in $scope, either use just trendV or use $scope.trendValues

Comment: the other reason I can think of is, assuming the TrendChartFactory.get is a service call, it actually returns a promise. So there is high chance that the statement next to it i.e getKpiValue executes even before the success call back (that sets the $scope.trendV) executes. Simple workaround is move the function call getKpiValue to within the callback function.

Comment: @Thangadurai should I define a callback function ?

Comment: @Thangadurai can you give me a hint on how to do this ? I have not used callback functions

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by angular.element

```
<div ng-app="ManagerApp">
    <div id="controller-id" ng-controller="ManagerCtrl">   
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("controller-id")).scope();
```

Once you have scope access your scope methods and variables using scope.scopeMethod() & scope.scopeVariable

A jsfiddle for detailed example :

https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/hfz3psuu/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var scope = angular.element(yourControllerDOMElement).scope();
var yourVariable = scope[yourVariableName];
```